# FreeTDS with SQL Server: multiple connections

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

I have a RHEL server Linux-Apache-PHP plus some separate Microsoft SQL Server 2008R2, that I access via FreeTDS.
I would like to open two separate connections, from inside a PHP script, which may go to the same SQL Server, or to two different servers.
When the two servers are the same, I encounter a problem.

```
$MyConn1 = mssql_connect( $ServerName, $User, $Password ) ;
$MyConn2 = mssql_connect( $ServerName, $User, $Password ) ;

print_r( $MyConn1 ) ; print "\n" ;
print_r( $MyConn2 ) ; print "\n" ;

mssql_select_db( "DB1", $MyConn1 ) ;
mssql_select_db( "DB2", $MyConn2 ) ;

$MyReturn = mssql_query( 'select db_name()', $MyConn1 ) ;
$t = mssql_fetch_row( $MyReturn ) ;
print $t[ 0 ] ;
```

The output is:

```
Resource id #2
Resource id #2
DB2
```

So, even if I make two separate calls, they return only one connection.
Is it possible to have two separate connections, pointing to the same server?

What I need to do is a table copy procedure, that receives the connection details from a configuration file, and that works both when the two servers are distinct and when they are the same.

Comment: Before you continue, plz STOP using mssql_* functions as they are deprecated and start using PDO or mysqli_*

Comment: This is a good long-term recommendation, but I have a lot of existing code to deal with for now